# Unable to redirect merchant site after successful payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am unable to redirect merchant site after successful payment even if I turn on redirect url in sandbox under Website Payment Preferences.

Please give a solution to get redirection to merchant site using Paypal sandbox after successful payment. I have already turn on redirect url option but still I am getting keep on 'loading...' process.

Comment: Can't help without seeing your code, bud.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a PHP answer for this because you posted it under PHP tag.
Try:

```
<?php
//http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

The only problem is you must not have any print out (echo, print_r, or any html out) before the header() function. Otherwise it won't work.
If you already have something and still want to redirect, check redirect using javascript.

Comment: Here is the JavaScript solution for it: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
//-->
</script>